# Is there a view controller for image crop and rotate works like iOS 8 photo.app?

Tags: ios, image, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I need a view controller for user to crop and rotate image.

And I think the UI which iOS8 photo app did is very awesome

But I found only these two :

https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor

These are useful, but when making image smaller than the crop area, to move or rotate the image is very difficult, and the respond is very weird.

After using these, I think the iOS8 photo app's crop and rotate function is much better
So is there a view controller performs image crop and rotate like iOS 8 photo app?

Answer (score 5):

Try The following:

https://github.com/itouch2/PhotoTweaks

https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor

They enables similar functionality as the native Photos app in iOS8.

Comment: how do you you use this in Swift 3? Teh CLImageEditor. If you have time to assist that is.