# iOS8 - Crop and Straighten image as built in photos tool

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crop, rotatetransform

In my app, i want users to click a photo, then i want to allow them to edit it for crop/rotate/straighten. Can i use built-in photos app for that? or is there any open-source/api to have similar view controller.

I know it's a possible duplicate of [Is there a view controller for image crop and rotate works like iOS 8 photo.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774106/is-there-a-view-controller-for-image-crop-and-rotate-works-like-ios-8-photo-app) but i found no answer here as well.Please let me know if it's possible?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.
`UIImagePickerViewController` `allowEditing` property, when set to `YES`, provides you a very simple cropping UI, but it doesn't support advanced rotation as iOS Photo app.

So you'll have to make it yourself.
The github projects in the question you linked might be a good starting point for that. ([here's another one](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor))

Good luck !

Comment: Do you know which UI control iOS photo app is using for rotation. Is it some custom wheel, or a built-in UI control?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one in Swift, you can continue to develop based on this: [QCropper](https://github.com/qchenqizhi/QCropper)